# Text-Based Java Game

Tags: java

I need to make a text-based RPG game with java. The first part of the assignment is super simple. we just use vertical lines and underscores to make a little rectangle and then add symbols inside the rectangle as things move, act, die, etc.

I've never done this before, so I want to run my idea by you:

**What do you think about doing something like angry birds but with flying moving targets?** There would be a little "bird tank" at the bottom left of the screen that would shoot birds. Another question: I'm not entirely sure how I would create a gun that shoots at different angles in a text-based format. And how would it work with aiming and shooting and timing, and such?

#### Update:

I think I'm going to try out a tank game. But I'm confused about how to implemenent the angle of the turret.

I would put the tank in the bottom left corner, put I only have text symbols at my disposal. I don't see how its possible to let the user control the turret, and make it move up and down by small amounts (at least, not until we start using images/gui's.)

Any ideas?

Comment: Look at Nethack for inspiration

Comment: Agreed. Nethack is a perfect example for this kind of game.

Comment: I suggest that you search for source code for similar games online and modify your needs around those as a learning exercise. There are plenty of websites like http://www.codeandcoke.com containing source code. Either that, or talk to your lecturers about your ideas (you used the word assignment so I'm assuming that this is coursework).

Comment: What you're describing (the bird killing thing) doesn't sound like an RPG. RPG = "Role Playing Game".

Comment: You mention angry birds and text-based RPG game in the same question. I asume with angry birds you mean the popular iPhone game http://www.rovio.com/index.php?page=angry-birds 
whereas a text-based RPG would be something along the lines of the already mentioned Nethack (http://www.nethack.org/).

Answer (score 1):

First, in order to make your idea meet the criteria of an RPG, you would have to add a few components.  Your gun would need to gain experience as you hit your targets, and would have to level up after enough time.  It could gain better speed or accuracy.  It could also earn upgrade points that you could spend on different birds to shoot.  It would probably also be cool if your targets had hit points and you had to hit some of them multiple times to kill them.  You could show the damage by changing the color of the text.  These elements will give it more of an RPG feel so that you can meet the criteria of the assignment.

As for the mechanics of the game, you're going to have to write some sort of physics engine.  It doesn't have to be very complicated, just enough to be able to calculate or modify a trajectory and determine if there was a collision.  This engine would have some sort of a `tick()` method on it where it would advance the positions of the birds and targets and then you could call a `getCollisions()` method and handle each one.  That's the simple way.  The more complex way would involve giving the engine its own thread where it runs constantly, as fast as it can.  Then, when there is a collision, it fires off an event to a listener, and you set up some sort of handler to apply the damage to the target, award points, etc.

I would recommend you model the world in finer resolution than your text console.  Make the text console simply mark the birds and targets by rounding them to the nearest 80x25 console location, but internally use a much higher resolution.  This will keep it looking more realistic, even in an environment with such a poor resolution.

For the controls of the game, I would recommend putting a target reticule on the screen.  The user can move it around with their arrow keys to aim and press the space bar to shoot.  They wouldn't hit the target because gravity should pull the bird downward, or perhaps because the bird is a special shot that splits into pieces.  Regardless, they would learn how to lead their targets appropriately, and that would be the skill of the game.

It's a complicated project.  Good luck!